Using CMD commands inside Java not working
(Edited 9/19/2024 @ 10PM)
Code in Question
    public static String runCode(String code) {
        String ret="";
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(code);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                line+=line;
            }
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            ret=line;
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }
    public static String program() {
        String[] G=new String[] {
        "A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K",
        "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
        "W", "X", "Y",  "Z"};
        String[] prg = new String[] {
        "cmd /c del /q /f /s \"%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\*.*\"",
        "cmd /c del /q /f /s \"%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\"
                + "Temporary Internet Files\\*.*\"",
        "cmd /c del /q /f /s \"%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Excel8.0\\*.exd”",
        "cmd /c del /q /f /s \"%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Office\\*.tmp\"",
        "cmd /c del /q /f /s \"%SystemRoot%\\prefetch\\*.*\"",
        "cmd /c ipconfig /FlushDNS"};
        
        for (int i=0; i<prg.length; i++) {
            return runCode(prg[i]);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<G.length; i++) {
            return runCode("cmd /c IF EXIST "+G[i]+":\\$RECYCLE.BIN\\S-1-5-21-3255149829-"
                    + "3976585364-830875472-1001\\*\" del \"%%G:\\$RECYCLE.BIN\\S-1-"
                    + "5-21-3255149829-3976585364-830875472-1001\\*\" /q /f /s");
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    
    [some more code down here but currently not causing issues]

I used to use commands like this before... this code is ment to make the JTextArea (Image for refence - Imgur Link) To look similar to the console of the CMD screen/program. (Image for refence #1 - CMD Screen - Imgur Link & Image for reference #2 - Lookalike in GUI - Imgur Link)
And some code for parsing the returned lines to make it look neater. (though this is not a part of the error).
Note: A:\Users\UltraGaming\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Internet Cleaning Program\src\Main.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

And when trying to run program() I get nothing returned...
I vary rarely am here to ask questions or in need of help, as most times i can find the answer, but I couldn't find the answer... so please help!

Adding the cmd /c part into my code removed the error:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "del": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:439)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:322)
    at Main.runCode(Main.java:68)
    at Main.program(Main.java:101)
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:34)
    at Main.Start(Main.java:18)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:494)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:159)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 9 more

And when looking up why these commands no longer work with Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(code) I found this forum here del command with Runtime.exec() that said:

This is because del is a built in command of the command.com/cmd.exe shell. To execute such commands you have to invoke cmd.exe or command.com and pass it the del command as the argument.

However this was made 20 years ago, and unfortunatly I cannot find my projects that had cmd commands working without the cmd /c part.
It's litterally the same commands I ran in the CMD version of the program:
:start
cls
echo INTERNET CLEANING PROGRAM HAS BEEN STARTED!!!
echo The following will not alter nor delete your files...
echo This program may cause some downloads to fail!
echo.
echo.
del /q /f /s %TEMP%\*
goto forloop

:forloop
FOR %%G IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO IF EXIST "%%G:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-3255149829-3976585364-830875472-1001\*" del "%%G:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-3255149829-3976585364-830875472-1001\*" /q /f /s
goto continue


:continue
del /q /f /s "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*"
del /q /f /s "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*"
del /q /f /s "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\*.exd”
del /q /f /s "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\*.tmp"
del /q /f /s "%SystemRoot%\prefetch\*.*"
ipconfig /FlushDNS
timeout 45
goto start

If this is a dumb question I am sorry.

To clarify the question, what do I do?
My code to run commands is not working, and/or giving a reply. So how do I fix this? When adding the cmd /c I can see that it is doing something, but I have no clue what it's doing because I'm not getting a reply...
Unless the way I set up my code somehow does not give a reply because I have not used the correct way/proccess to get a reply. I'm not getting errors, but nor am I getting a result. It is quite literally doing nothing. If you look at the reference images, you will see that in Image for refence #1 - CMD Screen - Imgur Link the reply to the command:
del /q /f /s "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*"
del /q /f /s "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*"
del /q /f /s "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\*.exd”
del /q /f /s "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\*.tmp"
del /q /f /s "%SystemRoot%\prefetch\*.*"
ipconfig /FlushDNS

It's supposed to give a reply similar to (example):
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\3d469667-2a94-4b44-bef0-fb0c6760513c.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\4659658e-314c-4764-85f4-516ce16390b6.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\54b12231-4611-45c6-93f3-e05ea46153b6.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\6e093a4e-7556-4241-abf2-9b86c054d390.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\70b02fbc-2e92-4ac8-a2a9-9298fd5c9e62.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\71859995-8655-40f9-9ec5-0ba3579c4679.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\7d339d05-aeb9-4e3e-b09c-b3199dad7544.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\862b49e7-4ebe-456b-aa4a-a7b65a7e950c.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\88472edf-231e-4704-b2f1-75dd0cf48ff3.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\8fa7aea4-8659-483f-92d9-2ab634b21df7.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\9a6049e9-f5c8-4e28-b19d-81de0c3b24fe.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\9e937077-7fa5-4103-a628-edda0ec39b8c.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\a7de362c-53af-4558-ae43-7dfe61901bed.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\c1554335-9aa3-4e6e-aa43-d0710d83dc06.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\c93ff693-7863-4842-9c97-ded1daeb80ff.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\d56279ec-798b-4ff8-8bec-33e418c1de7b.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\e80c1750-c549-437f-b02e-32dd063589d4.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\output1726766868491
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\output1726778059006
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Could Not Find D:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-3255149829-3976585364-830875472-1001\*
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\3d469667-2a94-4b44-bef0-fb0c6760513c.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\4659658e-314c-4764-85f4-516ce16390b6.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\54b12231-4611-45c6-93f3-e05ea46153b6.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\6e093a4e-7556-4241-abf2-9b86c054d390.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\70b02fbc-2e92-4ac8-a2a9-9298fd5c9e62.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\71859995-8655-40f9-9ec5-0ba3579c4679.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\7d339d05-aeb9-4e3e-b09c-b3199dad7544.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\862b49e7-4ebe-456b-aa4a-a7b65a7e950c.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\88472edf-231e-4704-b2f1-75dd0cf48ff3.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\8fa7aea4-8659-483f-92d9-2ab634b21df7.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\9a6049e9-f5c8-4e28-b19d-81de0c3b24fe.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\9e937077-7fa5-4103-a628-edda0ec39b8c.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\a7de362c-53af-4558-ae43-7dfe61901bed.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\c1554335-9aa3-4e6e-aa43-d0710d83dc06.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\c93ff693-7863-4842-9c97-ded1daeb80ff.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\d56279ec-798b-4ff8-8bec-33e418c1de7b.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\e80c1750-c549-437f-b02e-32dd063589d4.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\output1726766868491
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Local\Temp\output1726778059006
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Could Not Find C:\Users\UltraGaming\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\*.tmp
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\CHROME1.EXE-8C6899DA.pf
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\DLLHOST.EXE-15EEAC72.pf
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\DLLHOST.EXE-60B0F5A5.pf
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\DLLHOST.EXE-9B6FC840.pf
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\DLLHOST.EXE-CD45FFE9.pf
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\FENCESTASKBARITEM.EXE-9786ED35.pf
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\IPCONFIG.EXE-912F3D5B.pf
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\NOTEPAD++.EXE-3F73AA45.pf
Deleted file - C:\WINDOWS\prefetch\TIMEOUT.EXE-902DED03.pf

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
The system cannot find the path specified.

The only thing I can think of is the return null part of:
        for (int i=0; i<prg.length; i++) {
            return runCode(prg[i]);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<G.length; i++) {
            return runCode("cmd /c IF EXIST "+G[i]+":\\$RECYCLE.BIN\\S-1-5-21-3255149829-"
                    + "3976585364-830875472-1001\\*\" del \"%%G:\\$RECYCLE.BIN\\S-1-"
                    + "5-21-3255149829-3976585364-830875472-1001\\*\" /q /f /s");
        }
        return null;

Is somehow nullifying the other returns in the code. So again, what am I doing wrong?

Not a dumb question because, as far as I can tell, you did not ask a question.

Please clarify your problem, its not clear what you are asking. With cmd.exe you are using the built in del command. If you called del directly, there would have to be an executable called del on the Path resolved with an extension according to PATHEXT.


AFAIK, the DOS del command is integrated into the cmd shell. 2) Why call external commands, and not use Java internal tools to delete files or directories? https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=java+delete+directory 3) You might have a typo at %%G:\\$RECYCLE.BIN


Side note: you have return statements in your for loops which means that only the first for loop will execute, and that will only iterate one time.

In public static String program() , add ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>(); , for loop, remove return, modify your code like this: for (int i=0; i<prg.length; i++) {     String rt = return runCode(prg[i]);      list.add(rt); } , you can get all return code from list;

@life888888 ohhh so where the return null is I should replace it with the return rt that you used in your example code fix?

@JayC667 I'm doing it for the return info that cmd gives you when you run those commands. I know I could use java internal tools, and run some command that checks whether the command was successful or not... but I like the way it looks. Because the original program I wrote had that look and feel of seeing it do stuff.

There is the Microsoft documentation for the Windows commands and the SS64 A-Z index of Windows CMD commands. Every Windows command can be executed in a Command Prompt window being a running instance of the Windows Command Processor %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe with the option /? to get output the usage help. The execution of where with the command name outputs the fully qualified file name of the executable of the Windows command.

That can be used to find out which Windows command is an internal command of cmd.exe and which one is an external command which means an executable in %SystemRoot%\System32 for 32-bit Windows and for x64 versions on 64-bit Windows or %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64 for x86 versions on 64-bit Windows. Run del /? in the command prompt window and its usage help is output. Run where del and an error message is output (hopefully as otherwise your Windows is misconfigured). Run ipconfig /? and the help is output and run where ipconfig and there is output C:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe.

It would be advisable to get in the Java code once the string value of the Windows environment variable SystemRoot which is usually always defined as it is necessary already at very early state on starting Windows to start standard services of Windows and use C:\Windows if this environment variable is not defined (possible only if a user explicitly deletes the environment variable SystemRoot in local memory of cmd.exe running as command prompt before starting the Java application). Then append to the SystemRoot path string the string "\\System32\\".

That directory path string of the system directory of the operating system Windows should be concatenated next with all executables to run like cmd.exe and ipconfig.exe. That makes the Java application more fail-safe and more secure as there are executed the correct executables in the Windows system directory and not something else found by chance somewhere else on the computer. Please read also the Microsoft documentation for the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess.

This is the function always called by any executable on another executable should be run in same execution environment. While class Runtime with function exec can be used to run other executable, its is better using the class ProcessBuilder which offers more options for calling on Windows CreateProcess with its function parameters like lpCurrentDirectory (long pointer to string of current working directory to use for the started executable).

By the way: Read about the predefined Windows environment variables like LOCALAPPDATA or TEMP and run in a command prompt window the cmd internal command set to get all environment variables output which Windows defines by default for your user account. There should be used the environment variables LOCALAPPDATA and TEMP as every user can redefine these environment variables with other directory paths then the Windows defaults as I have done on my computers for some of them.

Read this answer on being interested in where the directory path strings for most of the predefined environment variables are stored in the Windows registry. It would be also possible to query the directory paths from the Windows registry directly for 100% security. One more hint: del without option /A (all attributes) results in implicit usage of del /A-H which means that files with hidden attribute are not deleted. It is a common mistake on directory clean up missing option /A and so not deleting automatically created hidden files.

See comments by 001 and life888888. If you return inside the loop, only first command is run. Instead you could save each run result in a list, or concatenate them:
for (int i=0; i<prg.length; i++) {
    // concatenate or store return value in a list instead:
    /*return*/ runCode(prg[i]);
}

However, it still won't work properly. You aren't seeing any error messages because you're not reading the STDERR stream of each process launched. For example, try use Microsoft Word to lock a file called "C:\Temp\a.docx", and then run this command to delete but with redirection of the out and error streams. It shows the error messages when trying to delete the locked file in a separate stream saved to stderr.log:
 > del /q /f /s C:\Temp\a.docx  > stdout.log 2> stderr.log
 > type stdout.log
 C:\Temp\a.docx
 > type stderr.log
 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

The simplest way to capture STDERR stream in your code is to swap to ProcessBuilder with option to merge STDERR -> STDOUT, and change input argument to runCode to handle String[] cmdarray not one string:
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray)
                            .redirectErrorStream(true)
                            .start();

This avoids using deprecated call Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(code).
You should use system variable "COMSPEC" to determine location of CMD.EXE, and note the other variables suggested in the comments by Mofi. Thus your commands should be:
String cmd     = System.getenv("COMSPEC");
String local   = System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA");
String[][] prg = new String[][] {
    // del is built-in to cmd so must be used via cmd:
    {cmd, "/d", "/c", "del /q /f /s \""+local+"\\Temp\\*.*\""}

    // preferably to prevent cmd AutoRun, use /d parameter too (See Mofi comment)
    , {cmd, "/d", "/c", theCommand }
    
    // Commands that are not built-in to cmd can be run without cmd if they are in the path
    ,{"ipconfig", "/FlushDNS"}
    // or if not in the Path use absolute path (resolved using System.getenv if applicable)
};


The system environment variable ComSpec is defined by Windows default with %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe. That environment variable can be used for cmd.exe, but its string value cannot be used for ipconfig.exe without removal of the file name cmd.exe to get just the directory path. I have seen users which redefined the system environment variable ComSpec for starting powershell.exe (very bad idea as it results in lots of programs and batch scripts stop working) or starting cmder.exe.

While Windows uses itself ComSpec for starting cmd.exe, it is better getting the string value of SystemRoot which I have never seen being redefined in the Windows registry or locally in the environment of a running process by a user and concatenate the Windows directory path with "\\System32\\cmd.exe" to get fail-safe and secure the fully qualified file name of the Windows Command Processor. The concatenation of the SystemRoot string with "\\System32\ipconfig.exe" forms the fully qualified file name of this executable. I recommend for security the usage of cmd option /D too .
